# Как сделать приватный чат в django channels

Tags: python, django, websocket, chat, django-channels

Как реализовать приватные чаты с django channels. В туториалах только про публичный чат. Как сделать безопасный диалоговый чат.

Comment: https://github.com/Bearle/django_private_chat2

Comment: Благодарю вас! Вы мне помогли

Comment: А где можно найти документацию по Django private chat2?

Comment: https://django-private-chat2.readthedocs.io

Comment: Я пробовал но не работает 404 doc not found